# setting a value in a form with a default value in primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I am working with Primefaces 5.1, I have a form in which there are columns with values `#{circuitController.newCircuit.project}`.

For this column, I want to set a default value from `#{projectController.selectedProject}` without asking the user to write a text.

How can I do that ?

```html
<h:form id="newUserForm">
    
  <p:panelGrid id="displayNewUser" columns="2" cellpadding="4"
 style="margin:0 auto;">
 <f:facet name="header">
     selected project : #{projectController.selectedProject.designation}
    </f:facet>
 <h:outputText value="Designation :" styleClass="title-text" />
 <p:inputText id="newCircuitDesignation"
   value="#{circuitController.newCircuit.designation}" required="true" />
      
 <h:outputText value="Description :" styleClass="title-text" />
 <p:inputText id="newCircuitDescription"
   value="#{circuitController.newCircuit.description}" required="true" />
      
     
 <h:outputText value="Start date :"
   styleClass="title-text" />
 <p:calendar id="newCircuitend"
   value="#{circuitController.newCircuit.date_deb}"
  enableManualInput="true" />

 <h:outputText value="End Date:" styleClass="title-text" />
 <p:calendar id="newCircuitstart"
   value="#{circuitController.newCircuit.date_fin}"
   enableManualInput="true" />
  
 <h:outputText value="Circuit designer:" />
 <p:selectOneMenu  id="user" required="true" effect="fold"
   editable="true" value="#{circuitController.newCircuit.user}"  var="user"
   itemValue="#{user}" 
       converter="project.management.converter.UserConverter">
   <f:attribute name="collectionType" value="java.util.ArrayList" />
   <f:selectItems value="#{designersSelectItems.values}" />

    <p:column>
     <h:outputText value="#{user.identity}" rendered="true"
          styleClass="data-text" />
   </p:column>
 </p:selectOneMenu>
      
 <h:outputText value="project :" />
 <p:inputText id="newCircuitpro"
   value="#{circuitController.newCircuit.project}" var="project" converter="project.management.converter.ProjectConverter"/>

 <f:facet name="footer">
 <p:commandButton value="Submit" update=":form1:circuit1, :growl"
   oncomplete=" handleSubmitRequest(xhr, status, args, 'newUserDlg','newUserForm');"
   actionListener="#{circuitController.addCircuit()}" icon="ui-save" />
   <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" icon="ui-reset">
      </p:commandButton>
   </f:facet>
 </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a @PostConstruct method to set the value before to render the view.

```
public class CircuitController {
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{projectController}")
    private ProjectController projectController;

    /* Getter and setter for projectController */
    /* And other properties of CircuitController */

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        newCircuit.setProject(projectController.getSelectedProject());
    }

}
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem , when i add a circuit the idProject is saved as NULL ;I think because the selectedProject is setted in the view layer ..Have you another solution please??

Comment: In your snippet code, you're showing `#{projectController.selectedProject.designation}`, so this field must to have some value. I supposed this value, `projectController.selectedProject`, is set before the posted view. Please, update your question adding all involved code.